# Why does xargs -t not display quotes?

Tags: quotes, xargs

Suppose you open two directories that you search for by `ls -Q` and `grep`

```
$ mkdir "example 1"
$ mkdir "example 2"
$ ls -Q | grep example | xargs -t nautilus
```

Then the option `-t` shows `nautilus example 1 example 2` without quotes. However, the folders are opened correctly.

```
$ ls -Q | grep example | xargs -t echo
echo example 1 example 2 
example 1 example 2
```

And to be totally complete, let me show the input for `xargs`:

```
$ ls -Q | grep example
"example 1"
"example 2"
```

So the quotes where there...

What is going on here? Where did the quotes go?

Comment: The quotes were *never* a part of the filename(s).  Do `ls example*` and you'll figure it.

Comment: Do `ls -Q | grep example` and you see what `-Q` does w.r.t quotes. :-)

Comment: Sweet. Never knew that `ls` provides an option to quote entries.

Comment: Yes, it's a very convenient flag once you know it.

Answer (score 7):

`xargs` considers quotes and backslash as special.  If you want it to emit quotes, you'll need to escape those.  Pass the `grep` output to `sed` to escape the quotes for you:

```
$ ls -Q | grep example | sed 's/"/\\"/g' | xargs echo
"example 1" "example 2"
```

Comment: The funny thing is that - apparently - NOT `nautilus example 1 example 2` but `nautilus "example 1" "example 2"` is called, because it works correctly (see nautilus example) WITHOUT adding escaped quotes. I would like to know why.

Comment: Also observe that `ls -Q | grep example | xargs -t -d '\n'` does pass the quotes unaltered.

Comment: I think it's a "bug" in xargs output: `ls -Q | grep example | tr '\n' ' ' | xargs -t nautilus` works fine, so it's not that secretly a new line is used as separator. However, `ls -Q | grep example | tr '"' ' ' | xargs -t nautilus` does not work. So, when actively removing the (undisplayed!) quotes, `xargs` will fail.